# How can I change a display of element dynamically in android WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I have a WebView in Android. I load page in webview from url and i want to hide some elements that the webpage actually has. I did it after page has loaded. And it give me only 'none' text in the webview nothing more. I tried as follows

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:window.document.getElementsByClassName('cdo-search')[0].style.display='none';");
    if (pd.isShowing()) {
         pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

How can we hide element that webpage actually has?

Comment: I believe a web view is simply used to display a webpage. If the web page needs to be dynamic, you would have to use another web technology such as .Asp, .php, .jsp or other JavaScript technologies used to dynamically populate the page when the URL is requested.

Comment: Yes, you can pass data as a string or other helper web clients. The first few paragraphs discuss the functionality and intended use cases of WebView. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was not it. after testing I found out that this solved the problem. The issue is not with android or webview. it's the way url based javascript execution works.

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl("javascript:function a(){window.document.getElementsByClassName('cdo-search')[0].style.display='none';}; a()");
    if (pd.isShowing()) {
         pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what's the reason but if i had to guess, what ever is returned by the statement you write in this format other than undefined, will be set as the document's html.

in other words, you cannot do any kind of assignment operation in outer scope, while executing JS in this format.

my testing method:

i put these two in the address-bar of this particular Stack overflow page.

`javascript:function a(){window.document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink')[0].style.display='none';}; a()`

`javascript:window.document.getElementsByClassName('question-hyperlink')[0].style.display='none';`

in the first attempt the qustion disappeared as expected but in second one, the page turned into "none".

Comment: i edited the answer. can you confirm if this solved your problem